# How to set “live-installer” media and “grub-installer” in Ubuntu 20 autoinstall configuration

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation

How to set "live-installer" media in Ubuntu 20 autoinstall configuration.

I searched in the docs but I didn't found the equivalents of the pressed for:

```
d-i live-installer/net-image
d-i grub-installer/bootdev
```

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 20. There is a 20.04 and a 20.10

Answer (score 1):

The equiv of `live-installer` is set on kernel cmdline when running the installer:

```
linux /vmlinuz ip=dhcp url=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/
```

As for specifying the boot device, that comes down to your cloud-init/autoinstall file, and I didn't find great documentation on how to set that up.  What I ended up doing was a manual install on my target hardware and then looking at `/var/log/installer` to see the YAML content to use as a starting place.  I started with a very basic cloud-init file and added my storage config to it:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: server-name
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
```

Also forgot to mention for my case, using https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart was helpful.